# Troubleshooting error when creating array from database values

Tags: php

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong with this php array? I"m trying to create a dynamic array but somehow it not working and get an Server internal error when attempting to access it from a browser

```
$index = 0;
$columnIndex = 0

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
  $test = array();
  $test[$arrayIndex] = $row[$columnIndex];
  $coumnIndex = 1;

  if(is_string($row[$number]))
  { 
    preg_match("/(?:\d+\.)?(?:\s*)?$stop?(?:\s*)?(.*):(.*)",{$row[$columnIndex]},$match1);     
    $test[$index] = '<p> <strong> . $match1[1] . </strong> . $match1[2] . </p>';
  }      

  ++$arrayIndex; 
  ++$columnIndex;   
}

$jsonData = json_encode($test);
echo $jsonData;
```

Comment: You're reinitialising the $test array every time you loop, that seems a bit pointless... where is $number being set?

Comment: Where is `$arrayIndex` defined?

Comment: Check your error log.  You probably have a syntax error here:  `{$row[$columnIndex]}`.

Comment: $coumnIndex = 1; should probably be $columnIndex = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error most likely because you're doing `$test[$arrayIndex] = $row[$columnIndex];` when I don't see `$arrayIndex` defined (thus it's null).  You can't set a null array index.

If you want a simple dynamic array in PHP, you could do something like this instead:

```
$test = array();
while(/* however you want to define your loop */) {
    $test[] = /* something */;
}
```

And you'll wind up with an array `$test` that contains whatever you put in `/* something */` on each line.  Look at the section entitled "Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax" on the [PHP Arrays](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) page.

Comment: also, `$coumnIndex = 1;` appears to have a typo

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
 $coumnIndex = 1;
```

Should be `columnIndex`.

You are also neglecting to close quotes before trying to concatenate a variable on the `$text[$index]` line.